# Angular4 loop through returned JSON object in .subscribe using typescript

Tags: javascript

I'm using http post in angular 4 to return a json object from an external API. Here is my function in typescript

```
getImages() {
       this.http.post('http://www.detdev.co.uk/photoapp/api/getFramesApp', {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
    })
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log("Error occured");
        }
      );
    }
```

I'm having trouble looping through the "res", which is just a JSON object - ive tried a few tutorials but they always reference a data object, am i missing something or doing it the wrong way?

The response from the api is in the following format as a json object:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"frame1","img_path":".\/frames\/1.png","uploaded_by":"1","upload_date":"2019-09-06
21:16:27","active":"1","username":"gaz","fname":"Gary","lname":"Smith"},{"id":"2","name":"frame2","img_path":".\/frames\/2.png","uploaded_by":"1","upload_date":"2019-09-06
21:16:27","active":"1","username":"gaz","fname":"Gary","lname":"Smith"},{"id":"3","name":"frame3","img_path":".\/frames\/3.png","uploaded_by":"1","upload_date":"2019-09-06
21:16:27","active":"1","username":"gaz","fname":"Gary","lname":"Smith"},{"id":"4","name":"frame4","img_path":".\/frames\/4.png","uploaded_by":"1","upload_date":"2019-09-06
21:17:03","active":"1","username":"gaz","fname":"Gary","lname":"Smith"},{"id":"5","name":"frame5","img_path":".\/frames\/5.png","uploaded_by":"1","upload_date":"2019-09-06
21:17:03","active":"1","username":"gaz","fname":"Gary","lname":"Smith"}]
```

Id like to loop over the res object in typescript and push img_path into a new array.

Comment: Please add a sample of how your response looks and what exactly you want to do on looping over the response to your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object

Comment: This is in typescript @WillAlexander

Comment: That is an array. This is extremely basic javascript. Please search how to loop a javascript array. And this has nothing to do with angular.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: I got that Gaz, but the concept is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to your getImage() to following . 
you can create your response format's interface though it is not mandatory but it will help you to understand your exact response format

```
interface ApiResponse {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  img_path: string,
  uploaded_by: string,
  active: string,
  username: string,
  fname: string,
  lname: string
}

  @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
    export class AppComponent  {
         imageList: string[] = [];

        getImages() {
               this.http.post('http://www.detdev.co.uk/photoapp/api/getFramesApp', {
              title: 'foo',
              body: 'bar',
              userId: 1
            })
              .subscribe(
                (res: ApiResponse[]) => {
                  for(let respObj of res){
                    this.imageList.push(respObj.img_path);
                  }
                },
                err => {
                  console.log("Error occured");
                }
              );
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following code under **console.log(res)** in the above example code. maybe that will help you to resolve your problem

```
result = res;
                const temp = [];

                result.forEach(element => {
                    temp.push(element.img_path);
                })

                console.log('temp value === ', temp);
```

Comment: result is an object you cant foreach on an object